# Evaluate with NaN

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to compare a signal with the help of `np.all()` with a reference signal. The reference can contain `np.nan`. At this NaN-position it does not matter if the signal fulfills the comparison condition. Following is a sample code. But this code does not work.
I could compare each element within a `for`-loop but is there a smart way to do this comparison?

```py
import numpy as np

reference = np.array([np.nan, 1])
signal = np.array([2, 2])

print np.all(reference < signal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit the comparison to the non-nan values with a proper slice. You could also use `np.finite` instead of `~np.isnan`

```
import numpy as np

reference = np.array([np.nan, 1])
signal = np.array([2, 2])
idx = ~np.isnan(reference)

print np.all(reference[idx] < signal[idx])
```

Comment: Thank you, works great. But there is a small mistake in your code. Please change `idx = ~np.isnan(signal)` to `idx = ~np.isnan(reference)`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I guess I didn't read your post carefully enough. I'm glad it helped, though!